# Cron Expression to execute cron triggers for 12 hours of a day?

Tags: cron, quartz-scheduler, quartz.net, cronexpression

I need a cron-expression (0 0/60 * * * ?) to fire application every 12 hours (twice a day).

Comment: for 12 hours a day as the title says, or every 12 hour as your post ?says (every 12 hour is twice a day, so, e.g. at .. 3 and 15. 0 3,15 * * *.)

Comment: @nos. every 12 hours i.e. twice a day...

Comment: @nos. if your answer is 0 3,15 ***, can you please explain me how? Why 15? and also post the answer in answer box so that i can mark it as "answered".

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use e.g. `0 0 3,15 * * ?` That'll run a job at 3am and 3pm. That's twice a day, with 12 hours between.
You could use `0 0 0/12 * * ?` which means every 12 hours. [Here's](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.2.x/tutorials/tutorial-lesson-06.html) some examples.

Comment: Can you please add cron expression in brief because i want to do the same but with this i got the error like 'Unexpected end of expression.'

Answer (score 3):

Some examples that fit your criteria:

```
30 */12 * * *
```

runs at 00:30:00 and 12:30:00 each day

```
0 3-15/12 * * *
```

runs at 03:00:00 and 15:00:00 each day

```
23 4,16 * * *
```

runs at 04:23:00 and 16:23:00 each day

Comment: @webyildirim: in that case you should use two cron lines for the different times that execute the same command. There is no way to specify that in a single line.